# Common list of irrational numbers and their decimal values?

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers, big-list

I have googled for a list like this and came up short. Does anyone know of a list containing many common irrational numbers (only integers, square root or cubed root) and their decimal values?

Comment: I think the problem with this question will be to define what it means a "common" irrational number. Would you, for example, be satisfied with the list of the values of $\sqrt{n}$ for $n=2,3,5,6,7,\ldots$ (in general, $n\in\mathbb N$, $n$ not a square)? Does $\pi$ need to feature on it? What about $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$?

Comment: Are you looking for http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html ?

Comment: Yes, Thank you! http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=sqrt%283%29&lookup_type=simple worked for me.